# RDP into a corporate laptop with Cisco VPN connected

Tags: networking, vpn, remote-desktop, cisco-anyconnect

I have a personal laptop with an local `192.168.0.*` IP address on the subnet `255.255.255.0` getting its IP address from an ISP router.

I have a corporate laptop connecting to the same network getting a local `192.168.0.*` address as well.

However, when I connect the Cisco AnyConnect VPN I'm also getting a network `10.53.46.*` address via the Cisco network adapter on the subnet `255.255.224.0`.

When I try to RDP into the corporate laptop, when it's connected to the VPN, even using the local `192.168.0.*` address, it cannot connect. I'm guessing this has something to do with the fact that the Cisco VPN is taking over the network traffic by connecting to an entirely different network.

Is there any way to make this work? Can I add static routing to my router to make this work?

Comment: Can you connect in the opposite direction, and does the AnyConnect client have "Deny local network access" disabled?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases if you are connected via VPN, the routing table is changed, and "all traffic" are going through VPN. It means that corporate laptop cannot communicate with any local addresses, because VPN isn’t aware of it. 
You need Split-Tunneling:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_tunneling

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/asa-5500-x-series-next-generation-firewalls/100936-asa8x-split-tunnel-anyconnect-config.html